# React Router rendering blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have this issue alot using react router, it just makes my whole app blank.

the ] at the end was a typo and wouldn't render a blank page, it would just give some normal error

This is my App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Route, Router, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/home';
import About from './components/about'; 
import Projects from './components/projects';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <header>
        <div className='logo'>MyPortfolio</div>
        <h2>Eshwar Tangirala</h2>
        <ul>
           <Link><li>Home</li></Link> 
           <Link to="/about"><li>About</li></Link>          
           <Link to="/projects"><li>Projects</li></Link>       
        </ul>
      </header>

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path="/about" element={<About/>}/>
        <Route path="projects" element={<Projects/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

My other components, like home, about, and projects just have an H1 with their name on it.

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed up your imports:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Route, Router, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

You've:

- Imported a `BrowserRouter` as the `Route` component
- Imported the low-level `Router` which is missing some required props to be passed to it

Fix the imports:

- Import `BrowserRouter` as `Router`
- Import the `Route` component

Correct imports

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

And if not a copy/paste typo, remove the trailing `]` on the `App` export:

`export default App;]` to `export default App;`.

[image: Edit react-router-rendering-blank-page]

Comment: I did, it still renders a blank page, i do not know why

Comment: @Eshwartangirala Kill and restart any development servers, it may just be looking at stale code. If it persists, please copy your code into a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live.

Comment: @Eshwartangirala I've added a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-rendering-blank-page-fsg2pn) to my answer. Unsurprisingly it works as expected. Have you been able to retest your code by restarting your development server locally?

Comment: hey thanks, but how do i go about restarting my dev server? Ive closed it out and clicked npm start multiple times.

Comment: @Eshwartangirala `ctrl-c`|`cmd-c` in the terminal to kill running processes, then `npm start`. You might want to fully close out of browser windows. If you're still having issue then can you try to create a *running* codesandbox demo of your code that reproduces the rendering issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Yes I would be down to inspect it live with you if that is what you mean. My email is eshwartangirala11@gmail.com.. My LinkedIn is https://www.linkedin.com/in/eshwar-tangirala-08973316b/.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a *running* example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/), an online IDE very similar to VScode. If it's running live then we can debug it over time to see what it's doing and how it's reacting.

Comment: Is there a way for me to import my files to codesandbox or should I just create it all from scratch in codesandbox? I'm not sure why only I have this issue, the fact that nobody know what's going on is weird, makes using router frustrating, might just make my portfolio with react-scroll.

Comment: @Eshwartangirala If you've hosted the code in a github repo you can simply import the entire repo, otherwise, yes, you'll need to upload the files or copy/paste the code in. This isn't entirely bad though as it allows you to really pare your code down to a minimal, reproducible example, and in doing so may even stumble across the issue yourself before getting it all ready for someone here.

Comment: Sounds good thanks a lot man. I'm typing it out now, how do you install  the router dependency for codesandbox.?

Comment: @Eshwartangirala There's a panel on the left that you add dependencies, or you can just type the import statement in the editor and it'll prompt you to add the dependency by clicking a button. Easy peasy.

Comment: Just did it and I'm doing it right now, I don't have everything in my project but I have router and two other components , how do I show it live with you?

Comment: It works perfectly fine in codesandbox, not sure why it doesnt in my vs code project

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-bohr-b4qisp?file=/src/comp/home.js:0-94

Comment: @Eshwartangirala CSB tends to install the latest versions of packages, so if you need to select a specific version you can do so in the `dependencies` section on the left. Also, make sure to save the code you add. I see where you added `about` and `home` files but they are empty.

Comment: Not sure if you saw my last comment but I will re=type it. It works totally fine in my CS https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-bohr-b4qisp?file=/src/comp/home.js:0-94. Still renders a blank white page in my React App

Comment: @Eshwartangirala Unfortunately there's not much we can do if we're not able to reproduce the issue. Something you might try is re-installing `react-router-dom`. Run `npm un -s react-router react-router-dom; npm i -s react-router-dom@latest`. This ensures a fresh install and that you are on the latest current version incase you previously had a slightly older version.

Comment: It is the latest version lol. Its wierd how this only happens to me. But thanks alot for your help I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If the code running in your editor is the same as the above snippet, you have a typo in your export (the extra `]`)

```
export default App;
```

Comment: Please flag the question as a typo

Answer (score 0):

Check your default App export remove this `]` you have an array `]` closing tag.
Your default export is should be like this:

```
export default App;
```

Not

```
export default App;]
```

Comment: Please flag the question as a typo

Comment: That was just a typo when I put in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the imports as stated above and then try to wrap your entire app in the browserRouter like this on the index.js, not the app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

(it might also be an issue with the react-router-dom version, since some of them use *Switch* instead of *Routes* , which one are you using? is something logged on the console when you run your app?)

Comment: I did everything you stated, plus fixed the above import, still doesn't work, it is the latest version of router. v6.