# React Router rendering a blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a router component in my `index.js` file and it seems to not work properly.

Here's what I've tried:

#### index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
// import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(


        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>

);
```

#### app.jsx

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The screen is blank and the console gives me this error

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

I'm following this tutorial: https://blog.logrocket.com/react-router-v6/. Using `react-router` version 6

Comment: Hi! This seems a duplicate to me, check https://stackoverflow.com/q/71161792/14264568

Comment: A good start app for React is https://glitch.com/edit/#!/glitch-hello-react

Comment: What is the react-router-dom version you are using ??

Comment: (It's on the post. Version 6)

Comment: Is this your complete [mcve]? I don't see an issue with this specific code and I don't see where you are rendering anything else that is (1) using a React hook and (2) considered page content. We need some debugging details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For react-router v6.4 create your router with `createBrowserRouter`

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
  Link,
} from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <Link to="about">About Us</Link>
      </div>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: "about",
    element: <div>About</div>,
  },
]);

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In V6 you can try this

```js
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom"
import "./index.css"
import App from "./App"

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
<>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
</>
)
```

Comment: it's v5 not v6 i want v6

Comment: I've edited it, and added example code.